# Null response from XML String Unmarshalling

Tags: xml, spring, soap, jaxb, unmarshalling

Having trouble unmarshalling and binding an XML response onto a POJO. At the end the Object only has null value, which could also mean the object class wasn't defined properly on my end.

**SOAP XML String**

```
String xmlToParse = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:env:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:soap.origin.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><eventResponse><result><field1>data1</field1><boolean1>false</boolean1><userId>123abc</userId><userinfo><boolean2>true</boolean2><field2>data2</field2><orgId>123abc</orgId><userCode xsi:nil="true"/></userinfo></result></eventResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>"
```

**ParseXML.java**

```
private EventResponse parseXmlResult(String xmlToParse){

   JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(EventResponse.class)
   SOAPMessage msg = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlToParse.getBytes()));
   Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
   EventResponse response = (EventResponse) um.unmarshall(message.getSOAPBody().extractAsDocument());
   return response;
}
```

**EventResponse class:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name=eventResponse", namespace="urn:soap.origin.com")
public class EventResponse{
   
   @XmlElement(name=LoginResult")
   private Result result;
}
```

**Result class:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonJsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Result{
   
   @XmlElement(name="field1", nillable="true")
   private String field1;

   @XmlElement(name="boolean2")
   private Boolean boolean2;

   @XmlElement(name="userId", nillable="true")
   private String userId;

   @XmlElement(name="GetUserInfo")
   private UserInfo userInfo;
}
```

**UserInfo class:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonJsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UserInfo{
   
   @XmlElement(name="boolean2")
   private Boolean boolean2;
 
   @XmlElement(name="field2", nillable="true")
   private String field2;

   @XmlElement(name="orgId")
   private String orgId;

   @XmlElement(name="userCode", nillable=true)
   private String userCode;
}
```

The XML definitions in case it helps:

```
<element name="eventResponse">
   <complexType>
      <sequence>
         <element name="result" type="tns:EventResult">
      </sequence>
   </complexType>
</element>

<complexType name "EventResult">
   <sequence>
      <element name="field1" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
      <element name="boolean1" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <element name="userId" type="tns:ID" nillable="true"/>
      <element name="userInfo" type="tns:GetUserInfo" minOccurs="0"/>
   </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name "GetUserInfo">
   <sequence>
      <element name="boolean2" type="xsd:boolean" />
      <element name="field2" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
      <element name="orgId" type="tns:ID"/>
      <element name="userCode" type="tns:string" nillable="true"/>
   </sequence>
</complexType>
```

I played with the naming for the @XmlElement annotation by switching between the xml tag and tns values but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out what the issue was. First, I needed to create a `GetUserInfo` class so I refactored the existing `UserInfo` class. After that, I needed to add the namespace used in the root element to all elements declared in the schema.